# Injecting SelectList objects into ViewData to enable using EditorFor on dropdown based properties

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have developed a system whereby I use an attribute to state which `SelectList` to use for an 'FK' property. I would appreciate some feedback mainly on by good practice, and also on any ways to do this better. Let me start my exposition with a demo view model:

```
public class DemoModel
{
    [DropDownList("LanguageSelect")]
    public int? LanguageId { get; set; }
    public SelectList LanguageSelect { get; set; }
}
```

Now when I use the Razor markup `@EditorFor(m => m.LanguageId)`, I get a drop-down populated from the `LanguageSelect` list. I get this because the `DropDownListAttrbute` class attaches the select list name to the `LanguageId` model:

```
public class DropDownListAttribute : UIHintAttribute, IMetadataAware
{
    public DropDownListAttribute(string selectListName) : base(KnownUiHints.DropDown, KnownPresentationLayers.Mvc, selectListName)
    {
        SelectListName = selectListName;
    }
    public string SelectListName { get; set; }
    public void OnMetadataCreated(ModelMetadata metadata)
    {
        var listProp = metadata.ContainerType.GetProperty(SelectListName);
        metadata.AdditionalValues[KnowMetadataKeys.SelectListName] = SelectListName;
    }
}
```

All my view models derive from `ViewModel`, which offers a `SelectListDictionary` property:

```
private IDictionary<string, SelectList> _selectListdictionary;
public virtual IDictionary<string, SelectList> SelectListDictionary
{
    get
    {
        if (_selectListdictionary == null)
        {
            var props = GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(SelectList));
            _selectListdictionary = props.ToDictionary(prop => prop.Name, prop => (SelectList)prop.GetValue(this, null));
        }
        return _selectListdictionary;
    }
}
```

In my base controller, I override the `View` method to pull the entire select list dictionary from the view model, and insert it into the view's viewdata, making it available for the editor template:

```
protected override ViewResult View(string viewName, string masterName, object model)
{
    var result = base.View(viewName, masterName, model);
    if ((model is ViewModel) && (!ViewData.ContainsKey(KnowMetadataKeys.ViewDataSelectLists)))
    {
        var vm = (ViewModel)model;
        result.ViewData.Add(KnowMetadataKeys.ViewDataSelectLists, vm.SelectListDictionary);
    }
    return result;
}
```

The editor template then retrieves the list it requires from the select list dictionary and builds a `select` input element:

```
@using Erisia.Constants
@{
    var list = (SelectList)ViewData.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues[ViewData.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues[KnowMetadataKeys.SelectListName].ToString()];
    var listWithSelected = new SelectList(list.Items, list.DataValueField, list.DataTextField, Model);
}
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model, listWithSelected, " - select - ")
```

So what say you all?

Comment: I stumbled across this post and noticed that in your DropDownListAttribute class, OnMetadataCreated(), you are assigning a value to local variable listProp, but not assigning that anywhere. Haven't had a chance to sift through it yet for MVC6 but something seems off with this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm assuming this code hasn't been reviewed yet because it's... **beautiful** - and I'm still searching for a better word. I mean, *wow that's clever, I want that!!*

The only thing I can see here, is in the `View` method:

> ```
> protected override ViewResult View(string viewName, string masterName, object model)
> {
>     var result = base.View(viewName, masterName, model);
>     if ((model is ViewModel) && (!ViewData.ContainsKey(KnowMetadataKeys.ViewDataSelectLists)))
>     {
>         var vm = (ViewModel)model;
>         result.ViewData.Add(KnowMetadataKeys.ViewDataSelectLists, vm.SelectListDictionary);
>     }
>     return result;
> }
> ```

I would suggest a *safe cast* instead of `model is ViewModel` followed by a cast, so it would look more like this - note that I dropped a few redundant parentheses:

```
protected override ViewResult View(string viewName, string masterName, object model)
{
    var result = base.View(viewName, masterName, model);
    var vm = model as ViewModel;
    if (vm != null && !ViewData.ContainsKey(KnowMetadataKeys.ViewDataSelectLists))
    {
        result.ViewData.Add(KnowMetadataKeys.ViewDataSelectLists, vm.SelectListDictionary);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Other than that, I agree with your naming (except *maybe* `vm` could be called `viewModel`, but `vm` is pretty descriptive in this specific context) and naming conventions, and there's nothing much left to say as far as I'm concerned - good job! :)